# How to get executables directory when executable is called from Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, vb.net, scheduled-tasks

I have a console application built into an .exe, and a WriteLog module built into a .dll. The WriteLog module is referenced within the console app project.
The module is using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() for creating a Log folder and writing .log files in the same folder next to the executable. This all works as expected when debugging on my dev machine, and also when the .exe is manually executed on the server. However, when the executable is called by Windows Task Scheduler the logs are written to the C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder. It seems that my Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() is returning the path of the parent process (taskeng.exe or taskmgr.exe) and not the path of the running executable.
I have tried a couple of different ways of getting the path like Environment.CurrentDirectory() with no success. How can I get my program to create the log files in the desired location in the same folder as the executable?

Notes: Both the console app and the WriteLog module are written in VB.Net 4.7.2 and the
Server is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Comment: As an alternative to the current directory, there are some assembly inspection options that will give you the current location.  You can use one of the shared `Get` methods to get a particular assembly, and then use the `Location` property to get its directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. I'm not real familiar with Task Scheduler. More a programmer than a SysAdmin. Here's my fix: In Task Scheduler, open the properties of the task, go to the Actions tab and edit the Start a program Action and set the optional "Start in" value to the path to the folder containing the executable. My logs are now written where I want them. Right next to the executable. (still using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() in sourcecode)

Comment: You were asking for the wrong information. What you want is the executable path. See `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath`. Unless you explicitly set the current directory you can't expect it to be anything in particular.

Comment: As stated above, this is a console app not a forms app. And in .NET Framework 4.7.2 Forms is not a member of System.Windows.

Comment: The code came from a console app that has no Windows forms in it. Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 14.8.4084

Comment: And it is supported 4.7.2 See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath

Answer (score 0):

**How to get executables directory**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Module AnythingYouWantToCallIt


    Sub Main
        Console.writeline(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath)
    End Sub 
End Module
```

And put this in a batch file to compile

```
 "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:exe /out:"%~dp0\Tee.exe" "%~dp0\Tee.vb"
```

The user chooses the current directory not the programmer, especially on console programs.

Windows on 99.9% of functions don't care if it's console or not. The only difference between a graphical and console program is the console program gets, if started by a graphical program, a new console. Or inherits the parent's console if started by a console program. Nothing stops a graphical program doing the same thing but under programmer direction rather than automatically.

Nothing stops a console program from creating windows and acting like MS Word or Notepad.